# Can <ehcache:config.../> be translated from XML to Java config?

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I am trying to go from xml-configuration to java-configuration for a spring project. I have managed to migrate everything except for this:

```
    <ehcache:annotation-driven />
    <ehcache:config cache-manager="cacheManager">
        <ehcache:evict-expired-elements interval="60" />
    </ehcache:config>
```

These namespaces are used:

```
        http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring
        http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd
```

I know that @EnableCaching enables spring's annotation-driven cache management, but I want to find something that has a 1:1 mapping with the xml config. Does anyone know if there are some annotations, interface to implement or something like that to replace the xml config described above? I suspect that there might be no Java config that exactly replaces the custom namespace, but maybe there is some modern replacement that could be used?